# Bespoke Like / Comment / Share functionality

Tags: comments, facebook-opengraph

One of my developers is building a Facebook tab application for a promotion we're running. During this promotion, some users will be given trophy awards. One of the pages in the tab application will list the trophies and their winners and we would like to have Like / Comment / Share links underneath them, like with URL shares:

[image: Like, Comment, Share example]

Now it would be relatively easy to hand-roll this functionality for items that have a distinct URL (and so can be nodes in the OpenGraph) and that's what I think we'll have to do for the blog-like functionality, I think. (For clarity's sake, none of the current Social Plugins meets the right needs.) But I can't see how to do so for these trophies, which don't have a distinct URL.

I am right in thinking that "things that don't have a unique URL" can't be OpenGraph nodes, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. Every node in the Open Graph has its own distinct URL.

The querystring is considered part of the URL: you could use it to make the URL unique but render the same page.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Presumably, if we wanted a few of these, they can be any old URL so long as we serve the right OG metadata for each request, right? So I could bind these things to `www.domain.com/placeholders/$id` and those things redirect real users to the appropriate page, but the Facebook crawler gets served appropriate metadata, according to the value of `$id` ? Or am I talking crazy?  :o)

Comment: nope, not crazy. At a unique URL, you can make Facebook see one thing, and the user redirect to another. You can do a JS redirect (which FB's crawler doesn't follow) or you can only redirect if the useragent string does NOT contain 'facebookexternalhit'